# Need a Mod rewrite regex solution for .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I moved my site to different server since then my all urls started showing up 404 error.

earlier my all urls were like this mysite.com/title-of-url

but now all such urls are getting 404 error, so i disabled seo friendly url feature on site admin and now i can access same page on
mysite.com/index.php/title-of-url

i tired to create some regex for .htaccess to do purpose like 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php/$1 [L]

but its working fine one depth of "/", i mean its working for mysite.com/first but not for mysite.com/first/second

I am looking for REGEX help regardng it so that 
mysite.com/first/second should gets rewritten to mysite.com/index.php/first/second as well as mysite.com/something gets rewritten to mysite.com/index.php/something..

looking forward for your kind help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it doesn't work with more `/`. Your rule says:

- Match from beginning: `^`
- (start grouping for `$1`: `(`)
- Match everything except the slash: `[^/]+`
- (end grouping: `)`)
- Match an optional leading slash `/?`
- Match to the end `$`

If you really want to match everything, use a dot instead of a character class, matching everything except the `/`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Do not forget to include a `RewriteCond` before it excluding existing files and directories, to avoid an infinite recursion. Fail to do this, and you'll end up with a 500 Internal Server Error. Complete code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Lekensteyn           
But i used RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /index.php/$1 [L]
as mentioned by you and it ended up in 500 internal server error :(

Comment: Is it possible for a regex to rewrite 
^mysite.com/depth1/depth2 to ^mysite.com/index.php/depth1/depth2
as well as ^mysite.com/depth1 to ^mysite.com/index.php/depth1 in a single rewrite rule.

I think if we rewrite mysite.com/somethingsomething to mysite.com/index.php/somethingsomething

Comment: Did you include a `RewriteCond` before the `RewriteRule`? See the bottom of my answer.